# Setting correct namespace in Antlr4.Runtime.Standard

Tags: c#, .net-core, antlr4, .net-standard

How do I set the namespace in the generated lexer/parser classes when using the Antlr4.Runtime.Standard (4.7.2) library under .NET Standard 2.0? I am using the following command line to generate the classes:

```
java -jar antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar -Dlanguage=CSharp arithmetic.g4
```

Setting the "Custom Tool Namespace" property in the .g4-file does not help.

Comment: Do you need to add the Custom Tool Namespace in the grammar file? Shouldn't it be added to a build file or something? I have little experience with the C# targets, but I can't imagine it  needs to be added to the g4 file...

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that I set the Custom Tool Namespace in the Visual Studio properties of the file. This used to work in Antlr4 for .NET Framework, but not in Antlr4 for .NET Standard. I guess I have to set it in the java command line, but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `-package ...`.

The following command:

```
java -jar antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar -Dlanguage=CSharp -package My.Namespace T.g4
```

generates source files like this:

```
namespace My.Namespace {
  ...
}
```